# How to print only certain block of content in a view

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that displays shipping details that you print and put on a box before shipping. But using Print module when you click the link it gives entire page to print with all the headers, footers and menus. I need only that block of text rendered by a view.

Also I couldn't make the Print module link appear in a view even though it claims it works, so I had to use View Footer Area and add some PHP to make link work.

```
<?php $current_url = getenv('REQUEST_URI'); ?>
<img src='/sites/all/modules/print/icons/print_icon.png'>
​<a href='/print<?php print $current_url; ?>'>Print</a>
```

But like I said it prints entire page and I need only view content.

Comment: see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463796/how-to-only-show-certain-parts-with-css-for-print
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only.
you just need handle it with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at this as most a front-end styling problem. Basically, you need to add print-only style rules that hide all the page elements you don't need. You can do this via an inline media query:

```
<style>
@media print {
  /* @TODO: Add other selectors that remove page elements
  header, footer, .my-custom-class, #my-custom-id {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Or a better, more portable, method is to just attach a custom print CSS stylesheet to whatever view that needs to be altered for printing:

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME').'/css/print-page.css', array('media' => 'print'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Shawn Conn's solution which is perfectly fine, you can add a separate `page.tpl.php` based on your path. You can define it your `page preprocess` function in `template.php`. Then in your tpl, display only page content. no other regions like header and footer etc.